# GPS CHC Landstar DB file format

Tags: sqlite, gps, measurement, wgs84

I've question about units in fields Db_GpsPt_dX,Db_GpsPt_dY from table Table_GpsPtArray_Point_Array located in every *.db (sqllite format) file maintained by Landstar application for GPS-RTK measurement. Unfortunatelly (CHC) Producer's support didn't response for my request, so i hope StackOverflow will be more helpful.

I know that for base points units are in ECEF units (WGS cartesian) but for rest of measured points there are values, that aren't corrected delta values either in ECEF, local XY oraz WGS84 (decimal). It is weird, units in given column should be written in the same format, but it isn't for that file.

Anyone has ideas about meaning of mentioned fields? Thanks for help.

Comment: post a part zof that table, to see the values , and post the column descriptions.

Comment: Table is available at [link](http://raportygps.pl/img/landstar-table.png).

Comment: WGS84XYZ/ECEF = 3746024.1596 ; 1342282.3814 ; 4968176.5525 [m]

First point from the table is base point (written in ECEF)
Concurrent measured points are in other format (looks like delta). For example second row (first measured point):
0.898... ; 0.344

For the first measured point (second row), delta vector between base and point is:
22.457 ; -5.118 ; 2.742 [m]

So delta can't be written in [m] (too small values) and in WGS84 (too large values).

Comment: What its seems is that all cordinates are ECEF measured from referecne ECEFm, there uis no mixture of coord systems,

Comment: If it was in ECEF then column should have values like 22.457, not small coefiicients like 0,898..etc (22,457 is delta in ECEF).

Comment: delta ECEF ist still related to the same coordinate system, so it is not an mix up of different Coordinate Refernce Systemms. using delta is a very good was to reduce data. (deltas later, could be stored as integers, etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK problem solved - i've just realized that 0,898 0,344 coefficients are an absolute coordinates in WGS84 datum written in radians.